# How many times do you need to beat mom and Satan etc to 100% the game?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I couldn't see the answer to this question but I know you have to beat certain bosses several times, and I know the fight between Mom's heart is replaced, but how many times do you need to beat the game before you 100% it?

Comment: This answer is pretty much infinite, considering RNG can be utterly disastrous to you and never give you items that you need to pick up to 100% the game. I don't think there is any sort of conceivable answer to this.

Comment: Are you playing the 2011 or 2014 edition of the game?

Comment: There's no answer to this question, there are items that you need to unlock and find that you don't get beating bosses. Angel Room's items, Meat boy and Bandage girl for example.

Comment: The *titles* of questions on this site.

Comment: Just part of the fun of Arqade @hBy2Py :D

Comment: For the sake of decreasing the clarity of the title: change "the game" to "it"?

Answer (score 14):

Okay because for 100% the answer would be infinite due to the 100% requirements require you to pick up **every single item in the game** Here are the bare minimum requirements to get every non-RNG boss related task done.

First I am making some assumptions here.

1. First you are playing as one character the entire time until the last step.
2. You are not picking up any items that transform you into another character Ankh or Judas' Shadow for example.
3. You never die and have to start over again.
4. You are playing on Hard mode to start with.
5. This list assumes you are unlocking all the characters during these runs and not requiring extra runs to unlock them.
6. We manage to get Boss Rush at during one of the runs on **each character**
7. We manage to get the Key from to unlock the Mega Satan room on one run per character after killing either Lamb or ???.
8. We manage to kill hush once for each character.
9. You manage to unlock The Lost before fighting Mom in a run.

Okay so here we go.

- One kill unlocks Mom's Heart.
- Killing Mom's Heart 11 times unlocks Sheol and Cathedral (requires 11 Mom kills as well)
- Killing Isaac and Satan 6 times each unlock the negative and Polaroid respectively. (Plus 12 to Mom and Mom's Heart kills)
- Killing The Lamb and ??? unlocks an item (Plus 2 to Mom and Mom's Heart. Plus 1 for Isaac and Satan.)
- Each character after this adds 2 Mom kills, 2 Mom's Heart kills, 1 Satan kill, 1 Isaac kill, 1 Lamb kill, and one ??? kill. Multiply the number of kills listed by 12 and add them to the lists (since we already beat the Lamb and ??? completely with one character.

Giving us:

- 50 Mom kills
- 49 Mom's Heart kills
- 19 Satan and Isaac Kills
- 13 Lamb and ??? kills
- 13 Boss Rushes
- 13 Hush Kills
- 13 Mega Satan Kills

**BUT WAIT THERE IS MORE!**

Who could forget about the challenges!

- Add 30 Mom kills since every challenge at least requires Mom.
- Add 17 Mom's Heart kills taking out challenges for Mom only.
- Add 3 Satan kills for challenges ending in Satan **(No challenge ends in the Lamb)**
- Add 5 for Isaac for challenges ending in ??? or Isaac.
- Add 1 for ??? for the one challenge ending in ???
- Add 1 for Mega Satan due to the challenge ending in a Mega Satan kill.

**But what about greed mode?**

Well with greed mode we need it to unlock one of our special characters for our completion. Some more assumptions with greed mode.

1. You are donating 50 coins a run to the greed machine.
2. You are switching characters regularly to get all the items from greed mode unlocked.
3. You are playing on Hard.

Okay so now that assumptions of greed mode are done we can do an easy calculation by dividing 1000 coins required for the character by 50 which we are donating every run giving us.

- 20 Ultra Greed kills

Which will max out our greed machine allowing us to complete the game with all characters.

**Which brings us to the moment of truth**

To beat all the non-rng content including the main game and challenges you need to kill.

- 80 Moms
- 66 Mom's Hearts
- 22 Satan's
- 24 Isaac's
- 20 Ultra Greeds
- 14 ???s
- 14 Mega Satan
- 13 Lambs
- 13 Boss Rushes
- 13 Hushes

So it would take between **101 to ∞** runs to unlock beat all of the boss related content 80 runs for Mom and the main game. 20 runs for Greed mode, and one extra run for the Lost.

Technically you could 100% the game in 101 runs if you managed to get absurdly lucky with RNG and manage to pick up every possible item in the game during your time playing but this is nearly impossible to happen.

Good luck trying to get only 101 runs to unlock all the content!

Comment: I don't think your math is right. At the end, when you "multiply the number of kills" for each character, you're including the 19 Mom/Mom's Heart kills in that number. Mom's Heart, Sheol, Cathedral, Isaac, Satan, The Lamb, and ??? only have to be unlocked once, not once per character.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right let me fix my math there. I want to make my overkill answer a correct overkill answer!

Comment: For full overkill, you could also add the total number of challenges to the number of runs required. Plus (for Afterbirth) the number of Greed runs.

Comment: Yeah sure why not give me a minute to do more math. MATH AWAY!

Comment: Looking at this now, I guess technically you could actually completely 100% the game in 101 runs if you got absurdly lucky with your drops along the way and managed to get every item in the game during your runs.

Comment: @Ramirez Hush and Ultra Greed are part of the Afterbirth expansion. I don't think OP mentioned having them. Might want to differentiate in your answer :)

Comment: @Vemonus Awww man that just means more work then since they didn't have a few characters in Afterbirth either x.x

Comment: "You are donating 50 coins a run to the greed machine", good luck! The greed machine is **evil**, sometimes it let me donate only a bunch of coins...

Comment: @pinckerman well again that is under my assumptions if I don't make assumptions for RNG like that the answer could vary like crazy. Besides this answer is as overkill as you can get for this question.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I meant that 50 coins per run is a bit optimistic.

Comment: @pinckerman oh I hear you but I mean like... this whole answer is a bit optimistic :P

Comment: The sad part is... all of these numbers will change when Afterbirth+ is released next Tuesday (2017 January 3).

Comment: @Powerlord don't worry once Afterbirth+ comes out and more information on the new completion comes out I'll be sure to update my overkill.

Comment: Now I just want to see someone TAS this run to get everything in the 101 runs

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get 100% completion simply by beating the game a bunch of times. There are several things you have to do to 100% the game:

1. Beat all challenge runs (High Brow, Waka Waka, etc.)
2. Unlock all characters (including the [secret character](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Lost)) (if playing the Afterbirth DLC, there's [another secret character](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Keeper) as well)
3. Unlock all items by finding/completing all secrets
4. Collect each item at least once (must be done in a non-seeded, non-challenge run) (can be done over the course of multiple runs)
5. Complete each character's "post-it note" by completing runs in hard mode. This must be done for each character, including the secret character(s).